# Edit text in List view is super bugged

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have no idea why, but the `EditText` is full of flaws when used within a `ListView`.

On Android 4.0 (and higher?) when the user types something in it, the `EditText` loses its focus and the soft keyboard disappears. I have fixed this by putting this code in the `Activity` using the `EditText`:

```
int apiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (apiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
else
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

But still, if I add an `OnFocusChangedListener` to the view, it is called **everytime** a new char is entered. That means that the problem is not 100% fixed.

Anyone else experienced this?